# useState React hook always returning initial value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

locationHistory is always an empty array in the following code:

```
export function LocationHistoryProvider({ history, children }) {
  const [locationHistory, setLocationHistory] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => history.listen((location, action) => {
    console.log('old state:', locationHistory)
    const newLocationHistory = locationHistory ? [...locationHistory, location.pathname] : [location.pathname]
    setLocationHistory(newLocationHistory)
  }), [history])

  return <LocationHistoryContext.Provider value={locationHistory}>{children}</LocationHistoryContext.Provider>
}
```

`console.log` always logs `[]`. I have tried doing exactly the same thing in a regular react class and it works fine, which leads me to think I am using hooks wrong.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: Removing the second argument to `useEffect` (`[history]`) fixes it. But why? The intention is that this effect will not need to be rerun on every rerender. Becuase it shouldn't need to be. I thought that was the way effects worked.

Adding an empty array also breaks it. It seems `[locationHistory]` must be added as the 2nd argument to `useEffect` which stops it from breaking (or no 2nd argument at all). But I am confused why this stops it from breaking? `history.listen` should run any time the location changes. Why does `useEffect` need to run again every time `locationHistory` changes, in order to avoid the aforementioned problem?

P.S. Play around with it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-ur4d3?fontsize=14  (thanks to lissitz for doing most the leg work there)

Comment: works fine here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-us546

Comment: Hmm, how strange :s

Comment: @lissitz I just realised you copied the code wrong. You didn't include the [history] variable in the correct place. When I removed the [history] argument altogether it started working. So thanks for accidentally finding that for me :D I'm still at a loss as to why including it breaks it though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting up a listener for the `history` object, right?

Assuming your `history` object will remain the same (the very same object reference) across multiple render, this is want you should do:

- Set up the listener, after 1st render (i.e: after mounting)
- Remove the listener, after unmount

For this you could do it like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  history.listen(()=>{//DO WHATEVER});
  return () => history.unsubscribe(); // PSEUDO CODE. YOU CAN RETURN A FUNCTION TO CANCEL YOUR LISTENER
},[]);   // THIS EMPTY ARRAY MAKES SURE YOUR EFFECT WILL ONLY RUN AFTER 1ST RENDER
```

But if your `history` object will change on every render, you'll need to:

- cancel the last listener (from the previous render) and
- set up a new listener every time your history object changes.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  history.listen(()=>{//DO SOMETHING});
  return () => history.unsubscribe(); // PSEUDO CODE. IN THIS CASE, YOU SHOULD RETURN A FUNCTION TO CANCEL YOUR LISTENER
},[history]);   // THIS ARRAY MAKES SURE YOUR EFFECT WILL RUN AFTER EVERY RENDER WITH A DIFFERENT `history` OBJECT
```

NOTE: `setState` functions are guaranteed to be the same instance across every render. So they don't need to be in the dependency array.

But if you want to access the current state inside of your `useEffect`. You shouldn't use it directly like you did with the `locationHistory` (you can, but if you do, you'll need to add it to the dependency array and your effect will run every time it changes). To avoid accessing it directly and adding it to the dependency array, you can do it like this, by using the functional form of the `setState` method.

```
setLocationHistory((prevState) => {
  if (prevState.length > 0) {
     // DO WHATEVER
  }
  return SOMETHING;  // I.E.: SOMETHING WILL BE YOUR NEW STATE
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Adding an empty array also breaks it in the same way as outlined in the question. So there's something which I must add (probably `locationHistory`) as the 2nd argument to `useEffect` which stops it from breaking. But I am confused why this stops it from breaking?

Also, why is it bad practice to access current state inside of `useEffect`? This is what the official tutorial does (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). P.S. `history.listen` (from the npm `history` library) returns an `unlisten` function so I shouldn't need to do anything else there

Comment: The last bit about `setLocationoHistory` fixes it (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-ur4d3?fontsize=14) I'm still not sure why, but I will study this more tonight, thanks for the insight! :)

Comment: See this FAQ: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often . It explains why sometimes you don't want to reference the current state in the effect.

Comment: ah, brilliant, just what i was looking for, thanks!